Как избежать предупреждений об устаревших методах в Data.DB
Если я добавляю в проект любой компонент, унаследованный от TDataset, при компиляции начинают сыпаться предупреждения вроде
«[dcc32 Warning] Data.DB.pas(2508): W1000 Symbol 'IProviderSupport' is deprecated: 'Use IProviderSupportNG instead'»
Можно ли как-то от них избавиться? Варианты вроде отключить предупреждения или убрать deprecated из Data.DB руками не рассматриваю, прятать исходники Data.DB тоже не хочется.
Может быть это я что-то не так делаю, и этих сообщений не должно быть?

Скройте вывод конкретного типа сообщений в настройках проекта.

«Конкретный» — это «Deprecated Symbol»? Не вариант, так скроются все предупреждения о deprecated-свойствах.
